# Export/Import Visual Studio 2015 rule set into SonarQube

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, continuous-integration, sonarqube

**Environment**: We are building C# code within Visual Studio 2015 and generating CodeAnalysis report using default ruleset available within Visual Studio 2015.
**Problem Statement**: While running same code into SonarQube integrated with our Continuous integration environment Jenkins, we are getting different Code analysis report, so we want to import *default* rule set of Visual studio 2015 to be used within SonarQube 5.6 or later (*I am ready to upgrade Sonar if there is solution*). But problem is SonarQube is not able to recognize ruleset starting with **CS**, like..

```
<Rules AnalyzerId="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp" RuleNamespace="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp">
<Rule Id="AD0001" Action="Error" />
<Rule Id="CS0028" Action="Error" />
<Rule Id="CS0078" Action="Error" />
<Rule Id="CS0105" Action="Error" />
<Rule Id="CS0108" Action="Error" />
<Rule Id="CS0109" Action="Error" />
```

I already have following plugins installed:

1. **Code Analyzer for C#**
2. **CodeCracker for C#**

Answer (score 4):

**Short answer:** there's no supported way of doing this. But you can try to hack around a bit to solve this.

**Long answer**

There are multiple problems that you would need to solve:

- The SonarQube Scanner for MsBuild, which you're probably using for pushing the analysis result to the SonarQube server, is pulling down the active rules from the SQ server. This is then being passed to the `CoreCompile` task in msbuild through the `ruleset` parameter. So even if you created your own, that would be removed from the parameters and changed to the Sonar one.
- The end step pushes issues to the SQ server, but the SQ server will ignore any rule ID that is not known. So in your case all `CS*` issues will be ignored.

At the moment I don't think there's an easy solution to these problems. The general suggestion would  be to create your SQ plugin, which defines all `CS*` rules. Get these rules into the ruleset file (probably between the begin and build phase), parse the output json file and send the results to the server. This would work, but it's a pretty big task, and there are many places where this can go haywire.

Another approach is to have a look at the [SonarQube Roslyn SDK](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarqube-roslyn-sdk). This SDK let's you create a SonarQube plugin from Roslyn nuget analyzers. If you create such a plugin, you'll see that it has 2-3 XML files embedded. These files describe the rules of the plugin. To support your case I would:

- Create a Roslyn analyzer package with one rule. (Which doesn't report any issues.)
- Change the embedded files to define the `CS*` rules. It's probably not that easy to get hold of a list of all `CS*` rules, but [this](http://source.roslyn.codeplex.com/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp/Errors/ErrorCode.cs,9b4287987c345755) could be a good start.
- Deploy the SQ plugin to the SQ server, and hope that it works.

Comment: I notified SonarSource about this feature request here: https://groups.google.com/d/topic/sonarqube/8RY_nR4GgEg/discussion

Comment: Shouldn't SonarQube Roslyn SDK be able to generate a Sonar plugin for Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp? I think it should, but I can't get it work. Here is the output when I try [:(](http://i.imgur.com/yR9AaQK.png)

Comment: I'm sure this scenario was not tested. BTW you can try specifying an earlier version. I'm pretty sure the SDK was not tested against packages built for Roslyn 2.0.

Comment: Okay, if I specify v1.2.2, it tells me "No analyzers were found in the package: Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp". When I check the path it is looking in (C:\Users\<me>\AppData\Local\Temp\.sonarqube.sdk\.nuget\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.1.2.2), indeed there is no /analyzers folder. I tried to create one and to put in it the Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Analyzers.dll I found in the Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Analyzers.1.1.0 folder. It generated a plugin but I can't see any rule...

Comment: What do you mean by "I can't see any rule"? Is it inside the plugin in the XML resources, or is it on SonarQube?

Comment: Sorry, but I think this won't work. The SonarQube Roslyn SDK looks for analyzers extending `DiagnosticAnalyzer` and checks their declared `DiagnosticDescriptor`s. There's nothing guaranteeing that the internal Roslyn issues are using the same architecture. In fact I think many of the issues are generated in the `Binder` class, which is not a `DiagnosticAnalyzer`.

Comment: I mean, when I look for the CSXXXX rules (the ones I'm trying to import) in SonarQube, I can't see them. And the generated rules.xml only has few RS rules. Anyway, thanks for your answers, it's well appreciated. I'll just hope they answer on the Googlegroup I guess :)

Comment: No problem. They will, they always do.